# Wait for an actor response indefinitely in a future akka java

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, akka

I have a non-actor-based piece of code which delegates some operations to an akka actor and I would like to wait this actor response indefinitely, I mean, until this actor returns a response whatever time it takes. The problem is I have not idea how to wait indefinitely in a Future with Pattern.ask and Await.result methods.

I would prefer something like this:

```
Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.inf());
Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(actor, msg, timeout);
String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
```

but this does not work because Timeout does not accept a Duration object as constructor parameter, it only accepts FiniteDuration objetcs...

Any idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You may never receive an answer, since message delivery is not 100% guaranteed.  As such, waiting indefinitely isn't a good approach -- you could well end up waiting forever.

You probably want some level of timeout (perhaps a long one, if it suits), and then a fallback case where you re-send your request as necessary.  This would be the more robust way of handling this situation.

Comment: FiniteDuration is enforced for good reasons. But as suggested, ``new TimeOut(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)`` should give you enough time to die several times.

Comment: You cannot timeout time more than 292 years otherwise you will get IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Duration is limited to 292 years. I think you can pass only 21474835 seconds maximum.

Comment: @Ravi while it is correct, that the maximum is 21474835 seconds this is only 248 days (not years).

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer : I'm not very experienced with Akka.

Suggestion : can't you forego the Timeout object and simply write

```
Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(actor, msg);
Await.result(f, Duration.Inf);
```

Either that, or use `Timeout timeout = Timeout.never`

Beware, however :

> A Timeout with infinite duration. Will never timeout. Use extreme
>   caution with this as it may cause memory leaks, blocked threads, or
>   may not even be supported by the receiver, which would result in an
>   exception.
>   (from the Akka API doc)

Comment: That cannot be done.

Have you seen [akka.pattern.Patterns API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/index.html#akka.pattern.Patterns$) ?

Comment: I have but have not used it yet. I was under the impression that since gracefulStop specifically asks for a FiniteDuration while ask only expects a Timeout, you could use Timeout.never. I might be mistaken (hence my disclaimer).

Comment: Timeout has not a method or member called never. Thanks for your interest in solving my trouble but your answer is completely wrong

Comment: This answer is very wrong. One of those functions doesn't exist (Timeout.never), the other can't be used in that place (Duration.Inf).

Comment: Sorry about that, I was referencing an older version of Akka (2.0) : http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/util/Timeout$.html